# How can I unregister observable objects in Quantlib python?

Tags: python, quantlib

I am a little new to Quantlib and wanted to check if there is a way to unregister notifications for observable objects in Quantlib python.

Searching around, I can see that the C++ library has methods like

```
registerWith(Settings::instance().evaluationDate());

unregisterWithAll()
```

But I can't seem to find them in the Python version of Quantlib or maybe I am not sure how to use them. Have these been exposed via the SWIG interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `unregisterWith` method?

```
import QuantLib as ql

flag = None
def raiseFlag():
    global flag
    flag = 1

me = ql.SimpleQuote(0.0)
obs = ql.Observer(raiseFlag)
obs.registerWith(me)
me.setValue(3.14)
if not flag:
    print("Case 1: Observer was not notified of market element change")
flag = None
obs.unregisterWith(me)
me.setValue(3.14)
if not flag:
    print("Case 2: Observer was not notified of market element change")
```